# Android: Toast shows up late when using threads

Tags: android, multithreading, toast

So I have code put together to download an image that's displayed in an `ImageView`, and I'm trying to put up a Toast when the user clicks the download button so they know some-thing's happening. The problem is that the Toast is coming up after a few seconds rather than when they have clicked the download button. I've tried wrapping it in a `runOnUiThread` method while it's in the new thread as well, but the issue is still there. Anyone able to point me in the right direction for fixing this? Code from the class is below.

```
public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_URL = "extra_image_url";

private ImageView mImage;
private ImageView mDownloadImage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_social_image_download );

    if( getIntent() == null || getIntent().getExtras() == null || !getIntent().getExtras().containsKey( EXTRA_IMAGE_URL ) ) {
        finish();
    }

    String imageUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString( EXTRA_IMAGE_URL, "" );

    if( TextUtils.isEmpty( imageUrl ) ) {
        finish();
    }

    mImage = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.image );
    mDownloadImage = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.download_button );

    mDownloadImage.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveImage();
        }
    });
    Picasso.with( this ).load( imageUrl ).into( mImage );
}

private void saveImage() {
    Toast.makeText( this, "Downloading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File file1 = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/" + getString( R.string.app_name ) );
            if( !file1.isDirectory() )
                file1.mkdir();

            File file = new File( file1.getPath() + "/" + (new Date()).getTime() + ".png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ((BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable() ).getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream( file );
                if( fout != null ) {
                    fout.write( out.toByteArray() );
                    fout.flush();
                    fout.close();
                }

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });


            } catch( IOException e ) {}
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: move `Toast.makeText` inside onClick

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. The Toast being before the method or the very first line before making the new Thread is the same thing.

Comment: Try moving Toast.makeText to just after .start() or after saveImage();

Comment: Nope, still a no go. I'll probably just shelf it until tomorrow.

Comment: Heh, that dude deleted his answers that weren't working and down voted the question. Classy.

Comment: @PaulRuiz: because when someone trying to understand problem and find a possible solution then he expect proper response from us instead of `Nope, still a no go.` or `Yeah, I did. Not the issue.` like un useful responses  and my answer is not wrong it is just not working because you are not able to implement in your code. it's not always possible to provide full running code. just way is important and i am sure current issue is must fix using `postDelayed` method

Comment: Actually, I implemented your solution since it's just a wrapper for the saveImage method. The postDelayed had no effect on the timing of the Toast, even when I played with the timer int. Given that, the postDelayed fix simply isn't the right direction.

Comment: @PaulRuiz: you know what is purpose of `postDelayed` method? this method execute runnable after time which we have specified in as last parameter and Toast default time is 2000 so try 2000 to pass

Comment: Yes, I've used them before ( various parts around some of my stuff on GitHub: https://github.com/PaulTR/AndroidDemoProjects ). As I said, it's not the solution to this problem.

Comment: @PaulRuiz: removed my down-vote you also do same thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you were to use an AsyncTask ,you could handle this.Because the [onPreExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) could give you the the toast that you need.

```
private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     @Override   
     protected void onPreExecute (){
        Toast.makeText( this, "Downloading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
     }

     @Override   
     protected void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        File file1 = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/" + getString( R.string.app_name ) );
            if( !file1.isDirectory() )
                file1.mkdir();

            File file = new File( file1.getPath() + "/" + (new Date()).getTime() + ".png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ((BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable() ).getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream( file );
                if( fout != null ) {
                    fout.write( out.toByteArray() );
                    fout.flush();
                    fout.close();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                    //Error handling.
            }

     }


     @Override   
     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the issue has nothing to do with the threads and toast. There's a couple second delay between when the activity is created and when the button is able to respond to a click. If the activity is started and I wait to press the download button until after four seconds, everything works as expected. Trying to hunt down what would cause the UI thread to hang in such a basic Activity now. Even when Picasso is removed and the bitmap is just passed as an extra in the intent, the issue persists.